# Can't rewrite php url using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This will be a niche question but I am having trouble rewriting my url.
I am trying to rewrite from /view.php?user=Alex0111 to view/Alex0111. I also have a second get variable of /view.php?user=Alex0111&id=5 which I want to be view/Alex0111/5 
Here are the contents of my .htaccess file

```
DirectoryIndex Home.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^view/([0-9A-Za-z]+) view.php?user=$1 [NC,L] #doesn't work causes internal error
```

I've checked this line of code multiple times to the tutorial I am following but I am missing the mark on something.

Comment: i also also wanting to ask this questions, thanks for asking by `1+` for you :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Comment: Isn't the first `RewriteRule` rewriting 'view/Alex0111' to 'view/Alex0111.php' ?

Comment: Are you sure the error is internal 500?

Comment: Try reordering your rules, put the first rule bellow..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace both of your rewrite rules with:

```
RewriteRule ^view/(.+)/(.+)  view.php?user=$1&id=$2  [NC,END,QSA]
```

Your first rewrite rule will interfere because it will rewrite the path as Markus mentioned in comments.

The `[END]` flag will throw an error if you have an old Apache version. In that case, use the `[L]`

The `[QSA]` flag tells the server to add any additional query parameters that the user sent. eg: *view/Alex01/5?**param=value***